# Resize Child Div to fit within Height bounds of parent div

Tags: html, css, svg

I think the problem I'm having is using SVG elements which automatically size to their container if the height and width is not set, which is the desired behavior. I need a way to automatically size the child div to never exceed the height of the parent container. I tried `position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0;` hoping it would work but it did not. Here is my code sample:

`html`:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id="logo">
    <svg version="1.1" id="logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 400.168 177.975" enable-background="new 0 0 400.168 177.975"
        xml:space="preserve">
            <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
    </svg>
```

`css`:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom:40%;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
#logo {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
}
```

My container logo has a svg as well, which is why it resizes but always maintains the width of the page (the limiting factor to maintain aspect ratio). Is there a way to keep my child div `id='logo'` restrained to the bounds (height and width) of div `id='container'`?

[Relevant fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/0pgefayc/2/).

Edit: Solution is to set a width first at a rate you're happy with (percentage of parent div) and set height to auto. It is true that height is not calculated unless specified.

Comment: You might wanna change your Fiddle to [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/0pgefayc/2/).

Comment: Thanks, I've updated it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add height: 100%; to the div

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom:40%;
    background-color:red;
    position:relative;
}
#logo {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Fiddle Here :** http://jsfiddle.net/mLrjr1sg/

Comment: This is giving me trouble. My understanding is that width is calculated first and then height, only if necessary. Putting only a height specification gives me a width that fill the whole div, and if I then specify the width to restrain it it overflows the div again.

Comment: But height: 100%; doesn't fills the div. See here : http://jsfiddle.net/mLrjr1sg/1/